# How do I create a shortcut on the home screen to change the time zone?

Tags: root-access, settings, home-screen-shortcuts

I want to be able to just tap a shortcut icon on the home screen and it would change the time to a predetermined time zone...instead of having to go to...Settings > Date & Time > Disable "Automatic date & time" > Disable "Automatic time zone" > Select "Select time zone > Scroll for the time zone I'm looking for > Select it.

Android 7 | Rooted

[image]

Comment: Via adb and root this is possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062827/how-do-i-change-timezone-using-adb You could try those commands e.g. in a shell like termux and then create a Termux-Widget on your home screen for starting the command.

Comment: Automate app can also do this. Requires a rooted device though.

Comment: @Firelord Just did it with Automate. Thanks! Funny, several months of trying to do this and I've always been using Automate but couldn't create it because "date & time" in Automate doesn't have a time zone option..for some reason, after reading your comment, I had a look at it again and searched "time zone" this time and sure enough, it was right there - the option to select a time zone. One problem though, it doesn't disable the Automatic date and time and time zone, so it keeps going back to local time.

Comment: @JJrussel good to know it helped. I didn't know either that Automate offered this feature. I saw your question and the first thing I did was to go through the automation apps I had to see if they offered this feature. Found one, so told you about it.

Comment: With Automate, use the App start block to open the Date & time window. Then use either Interact or Interact touch blocks to disable/enable Automatic time zone.

Comment: @Reddy Lutonadio Could you give a little more explanation please? I tried to understand but I'm failing. You say "use the App start block". Is that an app called "Start Block"? I can't find such an app. Then you say use "Interact or Interact touch blocks to disable/enable Automatic time zone"...again, are those apps or do you mean to start a flow in Automate? Obviously, I need a guide geared towards a more novice crowd :)

Comment: Create a flow in Automate, then use the mentioned blocks.

Comment: @Reddy Lutonadio There is no such think as "start block" in Automate https://imgur.com/a/0q2g1kV

Comment: @JJrussel I's right there [App start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC5Ro.png).

Comment: @Reddy Lutonadio Which drop down menu for "date & time"? All of them seem to be only apps. Date & time is not an app so not listed. https://imgur.com/G2e5iFs